# Get Custom Attribute in Category

Tags: category, custom-attributes

i am using magento enterprise edition, i have created a module to add custom attributes to the categories , the attributes are visible in adminhtml and they are saved propertly but when i try to retrieve the category on frontend, it doesnot contain the attributes i just created and i alredy reindex all but nothing, the problem is magento enterprise because i tried in magento community and works fine, here is my code

```
   $installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
    $installer->startSetup();
    $label="whatever";

 $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', $label, array(
                   'type' => 'int',
                   'label' => $label,
                   'input' => 'select',
                   'source'  => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
                   'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                   'visible' => true,
                   'required' => false,
                   'default' => '0',
                   "visible_on_front"  => true,
                   'group' => 'filter9',
               ));
```

here is the config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>

 <modules>
     <Qxd_Categories>
         <version>0.0.6</version>
     </Qxd_Categories>
 </modules>
         <admin>
             <routers>
                 <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                    <modules>
                             <Qxd_Categories before="Mage_Adminhtml">Qxd_Categories_Adminhtml</Qxd_Categories>
                         </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>
            </routers>
        </admin>

<global>
    <resources>
        <qxd_categories_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Qxd_Categories</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </qxd_categories_setup>
        <qxd_categories_setup_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </qxd_categories_setup_write>
        <qxd_categories_setup_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </qxd_categories_setup_read>
    </resources>
</global>

 </config>
```

And this is front end where i am trying to  reindex data and retrieve the category:

```
 $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(5);   $process->reindexAll();
  $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(6);    $process->reindexAll();
 foreach ($categories as $category) {



$cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category->getId());
if($cat->getData('entity_id')=='7'){
        var_dump($cat->getData()); // all but my attribute
        var_dump($cat); // my attribute is not there :(

        var_dump($cat->getName()); // My  Category Name
     }

 }
```

Any suggestion is welcome, please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attribute code is  whatever when you can this field  by `$cat->getWhatever();` 
If this  attribute is what_ever  the  `_ (underscore make next letter of capital)` thus

```
$cat->getWhatEver();
```

Comment: ignore that line, when i did var_dump($cat->getData()), my attribute is not there. or when i do var_dump($cat) my attribute is not there :(

Answer (score 4):

You can get all your categories for a specific store using a helper:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories();
```

Then you can add your attribute to this collection by adding the following to your modules config.xml.

```
<frontend>
    <category>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                <your_attribute/>
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </category>
</frontend>
```

Comment: the problem is that the attributes must be created dynamically and in adminhtml the user decides the value  so i cant use xml for this =S